# cannot convert lambda expression to type object because it is not a delegate type

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, razor, lambda, view

I have a GET method that returns the json object from the web API. I have created the corresponding model. When I try to get the values into the view, I am getting this error:

> cannot convert lambda expression to type object because it is not a delegate type

I need to get the value of location property from the model.

Controller:

```cs
public IActionResult AddEditLoadBalancer(string subscriptionId, string resourceGroupName, string loadBalancerName, string subscriptionName)
{
    try
    {
        ViewBag.LBName = loadBalancerName;
        ViewBag.SubscriptionName = subscriptionName;
        var token = HttpContext.Session.GetString("Token");
        var tenantid = HttpContext.Session.GetString("TenantId");

        var sessionId = HttpContext.Session.GetString("SessionId");
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(token) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(tenantid))
        {
            var path = $"/api/PaasCatalog/AddEditLoadBalancer?subscriptionId=" + subscriptionId + "&resourceGroupName=" + resourceGroupName + "&loadBalancerName=" + loadBalancerName;
            var response = _httpClient.SendRequestWithBearerTokenAsync(HttpMethod.Get, path, null, token, tenantid, _cancellationToken, sessionId).Result;
            if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                return null;
            var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            if (result == null)
                return null;
            var jsontemplates = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AddEditLoadBalancer>(result);

            return View(jsontemplates);
        }
        else
        {
            RedirectToAction("SignOut", "Session");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _errorLogger.LogMessage(LogLevelInfo.Error, ex);
        return null;
    }
    return null;
}
```

View:

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Location:</label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.location, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly" } })
    </div>
</div>
```

Where am I going wrong? Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: You didn't mention what error you get! Add your problem to the question.

Comment: What/where is your `Model` for the `View`? Does it have a `location` property?

Answer (score 1):

Everything is correct in the code. All I had to do was clean and rebuild the entire application and stop all the worker processes that were running. This solved my issue.